# Access dom element with vuejs and vuetify in v-tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a div tag with an 'id="meet"' into v-tabs.

I need to access the node of this tag after I click a tab. I am using

```
let node=document.querySelector("#meet").
```

My problem is that it always returns "null". Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/luizalves/pen/WNrepxz

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that after $nextTick you will see DOM element immediately.

```
 <div id="meet"></div>
<button @click="onTest">test</button>
...
methods: {
onTest () {
      let node=document.querySelector("#meet");
      console.log('meet here',node)  
    },
```

After you clicked `test` you'll see in a console:

```
"meet here" "<div id='meet'></div>"
```

You can try to extract this div with an unique id into a separate component and inside it you can use `mounted` hook to know that it exists in DOM

Answer (score 0):

Of course, according to vuetify docs, you may add **eager** prop to *v-tab-item* component, and that's it, but...possibly you are doing something wrong.

It's not a good idea to always add this prop because you are losing one of the vuetify 2.X advantages - lazy loading. This may lead to big performance problems if there are many elements on the tab.

Maybe it would be better if you will work directly with reactive variables (like variables in v-model directive), not DOM objects.

Comment: My div id will be replaced wih Jitsi video conference iframe. I don´t know if it is possible using reactive variables.